Lua attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value (local 'answerQuestion')
Everytime I get Nil as soon as place number and i press Enter.
I have this code working on Replit. But as soon as I put it in VSCode I cannot get past this arithmetic on a nil value. I have tried io.read("*n") and still get it coming back saying that answerQuestion is nil after i enter a number. I am not finding my specific issue in the search here or DuckDuckGo. Running lua 5.4.4 on MacBook Pro.
io.write('YOUR ANSWER: ')
local answerQuestion = io.read()
answerQuestion = tonumber(answerQuestion)
print(answerQuestion)
if answerQuestion + 3 == 7 then
  table.insert(correctTable, n)
  CorrectAnswer = CorrectAnswer + 1
else
  -- print('Wrong!')
  table.insert(incorrectTable, n) -- add these to the rest of the list when they return.
end ```


You mentioned this code works on replit, what are you using to run it in vscode?

Well I started writing this in Replit because i had my ipad with me and I could make Lua work on replit since there is no VSCode on ipad. Then I transferred a working script from replit over to vsCode for some more tweaking of it. But cannot get past the io.read() into the variable error. Keeps coming up nil. I am lost just trying to get past that one small issue. tried putting "*n" inside the () but still the same error. Not sure what you mean by what am I using to run it in VSCode. It is on my MacBook Pro with M1 chip. Using LuaHelper And Lua 5.3.

IIRC this is a problem with LuaHelper, try other lua debuggers.

@shingo Might need a little help here. I cannot seem to find the Lua Helper extension in the installed extensions. I have other Lua Debuggers installed. I cannot figure out how to set one of them as the default debugger in VsCode In the launch.json there is one called Debug Lua Interpreter which I don't see an extension for that either. In searching set debugger in vscode. the explanations coming are old like 2019 nothing really new. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Well I cannot post an answer because of something 8 years ago. But I uninstalled all Lua Extensions. Which opened up a can of worms. But installed Lua Debug and Lua Debugger. Did a complete restart reboot. And now I am not having the nil problem any longer. Thanks for the guidance to get me somewhere.
