Second Example in Lua 2nd Book Attempts To Perform Arithmetic On Nil Value
I'm wondering if this is a version mismatch?
I needed to use a Lua 5.1.x version to interface with Love2D [Due to use of LuaJIT]
The second example in the book, as I come to grips with how it wants syntax to work, throws an exception that, after reviewing what is in the book to my code, am lost as to why the inputted value is not getting put into the functions variable.
-- defines a factorial function
function fact (n)
    if n == 0 then
        return 1
    else
        return n * fact(n-1)
    end
end

print("Enter a number:")
a = io.read("*number")  -- read a number
print(fact(a))

Attached is a snapshot of that section in the book;
It feels bizarre that the official book would be wrong so I am assuming it is something I am doing and I must be silly.
The exact error, which was already described above:
 attempt to perform arithmetic on local 'n' (a nil value)
As far as I can tell, the "a" variable is not getting it's value transferred to "n" when it tries to run fact(a) in print().
After searching online, I have not found an obvious answer and thus is why I am wondering if this is something more related to setting up Lua wrong on my system. [Hello World works and typing "Lua" into the command line both show that the system is using the provided 5.1 Lua]
Thank you for your time! ♥

This code is fully operational. It requests a number and outputs a factorial. (I tested it in VS Code.)

Maybe it's how you run the file. Try saving that as fac.lua and running in a terminal $ lua fac.lua

Some lua runner extensions in VS Code will input some control characters on startup, here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78816573/lua-attempt-to-perform-arithmetic-on-a-nil-value-local-answerquestion
